# UIStackview keep subviews right align, even if other view is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, uistackview

I have horizontal UIStackview (width = screenwidth height = 40) with 2 buttons. I set width and height of both buttons to 40. The UIStackview Alignment is Fill and Distribution is Equal spacing.

Now first button is on leading side of stackview and second button is trailing side of stackview which is ok for me.

When I hide the button 2 then button 1 is coming to middle of stackview, which I dont want. How do make it happen?

Comment: I don't think you want to sett the UIButton widths in this case? Let the UIStackview grow or shrink the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

It is by design that hidden arranged subviews are not only hidden but no longer contribute to the layout either. It's a major feature that cannot be achieved easily with auto layout.

If you want to prevent this, then you can wrap your view within another view. Instead of hiding the direct subview of the UIStackView (the wrapper view in the new setup), hide the inner view (the same way as in the old setup except it is now nested). As the direct subview is visible, UIStackView won't reclaim the space. But the user can't see any content as the view content is hidden.

**Other workaround**

Instead of hiding the subview, you can just turn its alpha to 0. This way the subview won't be visible but it will participate in the layout.